# Name assigned to the scrolling images in the camera app

Tags: iphone, camera

Odd question, but i am trying to recall what the small horizontal scrolling set of thumbnail images under a photo is called (in the iPhone camera app)

Answer (score 1):

The term i sought was "scrubber".. Caught a reference watching "Altered Carbon" and my brain immediately recalled this question from weeks ago. ;) I found a few references on the web to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't seem to have given it a name, referring to it as ‘the thumbnails’ in the user guide.

> While viewing a photo, swipe the thumbnails to browse photos, then tap a thumbnail

[View photos and videos - iPhone User Guide](https://help.apple.com/iphone/11/#/iph3d267610)

The trouble with referring to it by ‘thumbnails’ is that it is heavily based on context. For example, if someone just said ‘the thumbnails in the Photos app’ I’d first think of the main grid of thumbnails before a photo is selected.

Comment: I too saw that, but i know that when the UI was improved, there was a specific word, something like "scratcher" etc.. I am asking as i am seeking git repositories etc that may help me put together something similar and wanted to search stacker with that particular term.